# CMS or framework options for a user generated content website?

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

I'm thinking of building a pretty simple website where users can post different content types to different sections. Say there will be a video section where the only fields are a link field for a video URL and some tags, a shop section for stores related to the website's theme where the available fields are for a picture, an address and a comment, a gallery section where only images can be posted...
I know how to do this in django, but I don't want to use that because a)it's not so easy to find some cheap throwaway hosting for a little experiment and b)I want to see if there's other simple solutions out there and hopefully learn something about PHP CMSs/frameworks in the way, cos I've only really used Wordpress. 
So my question is - is there a relatively easy CMS out there that let's me create a bunch of custom content types like that?Or is that kind of flexibility something that you can only get with frameworks?
Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need too much customization You can achieve this with wordpress without any problem.

Learn about custom post types in wordpress ( search the official doc or check this out http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress )

I'd go with the following plugin / lib:

http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/ for the custom fields on video and shop post types.

Nextgen gallery plugin for the gallery (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/)

Have fun ;)

Comment: thank you there!I started playing with joomla and wpress and i was worried that i was stuck with the plain vanilla content types that show up by default, guess i should have looked around more :)